# Gradient is always zero in autograd.grad()

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I implemented a custom loss function, which looks like this:
[image: objective function.]

However, the gradient of this function is always zero and I don't understand why.
The code for the objective function:

```
def objective(p, output):
  x,y = p
  a = minA
  b = minB
  r = 0.1

  XA = 1/2 -1/2 * torch.tanh(100*((x - a[0])**2 + (y - a[1])**2 - (r + 0.02)**2))
  XB = 1/2 -1/2 * torch.tanh(100*((x - b[0])**2 + (y - b[1])**2 - (r + 0.02)**2))

  q = (1-XA)*((1-XB)* output + (XB))

  output_grad, _ = torch.autograd.grad(q, (x,y))
  output_grad.requires_grad_()
  q = output_grad**2

  return q
```

And the code for training the model (which is a simple, fully connected NN):

```
model = NN(input_size)
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
for e in range(epochs) :
  for configuration in total:
    print("Train for configuration", configuration)
    # Training pass
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    #output is q~
    output = model(configuration)

    #loss is the objective function we defined
    loss = objective(configuration, output.item())
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

I really think the problem is in the output_grad, _ = torch.autograd.grad(q, (x,y)).
(During he training, "configuration" is a point sampled from a distribution identified by the coordinates x and y).
Thanks!!

Here I provide the code on a google colab session:
[Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JIGSrhd3ivqp_agDoO7wwF26cIjQ4LAN?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. In this case, preferably example values that show the problem.

Comment: Thanks @GoodDeeds, I linked a google colab session with the code.

Answer (score 1):

[Tanh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Tanh) is a bounded function and converges quite quickly to 1. Your XA and XB points are defined as

```
XA = 1/2 - 1/2 * torch.tanh(100*(z1 + z2 - z0))
XB = 1/2 - 1/2 * torch.tanh(100*(z3 + z4 - z0))
```

Since `z1 + z2 - z0` and `z3 + z4 - z0` are rather close to `1`, you will end up with an input close to 100. This means the tanh will output `1`, resulting in `XA` and `XB` begin zeros. You might not want to have this `100` coefficient if you want to have non zero outputs.

Comment: Thank you, I could've guessed that this was the reason. However, in the paper from which I took this implementation, they used a fact of 1000 even. I'll try to play around with the function, thanks again tho

Comment: I guess this will depend on your data range. Could you provide the reference for that paper? Thank you.

Comment: https://openreview.net/pdf?id=H1lPUiRcYQ 
I am referring to equation 20

Comment: Ok, did you check that they were using the same kind of data?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am. The way I sample the configuration is different, but I end up with "configurations", or points, which are identified by the coordinates (x,y) (or more, if the dimensionality is higher).